# How to refresh the contents in widget using pyqt4?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here in my program I get the data from API. If any one ordered that data I want to see in my window without reopen the app. Here I declared the function when I press the refresh button I want to update data but same data, but when I press refresh button same data is adding in double times. Given below is my sample code here I mention dictionaries in place of my API. How can I update the data.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys, collections
from functools import partial
class InfoWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, info, parent=None):
        super(InfoWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self._info = info

        date_label = QtGui.QLabel("{}   {}".format(info["Date"], info["Id"]), alignment= QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, objectName="small")
        amount_label = QtGui.QLabel("Amount:{}".format(info["Amount"]))
        shopping_label = QtGui.QLabel("Shopping :{}".format(info["Shopping"]))
        ordercity_label = QtGui.QLabel("Order City :{}".format(info["Order_City"]))
        orderstate_label = QtGui.QLabel("Order State :{}".format(info["Order_State"]))
        hline = QtGui.QFrame(frameShape=QtGui.QFrame.HLine)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(date_label)
        lay.addWidget(amount_label)
        lay.addWidget(shopping_label)
        lay.addWidget(ordercity_label)
        lay.addWidget(orderstate_label)
        lay.addWidget(hline)

    @property
    def info(self):
        return self._info

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
        super(InfoWidget, self).mousePressEvent(event)

class Orders(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Orders, self).__init__(parent)
        self.Online_order_dict = [
            {"Date" : "jan-24-2019", "Id" : "#175", "Amount" : "191 rs", "Shopping" : "Online", "Order_City" : "Hyderbad", "Order_State" : "TELANGANA"},
            {"Date" : "jan-25-2019", "Id" : "#186", "Amount" : "200 Rs", "Shopping" : "Online", "Order_City" : "Hyderbad", "Order_State" : "TELANGANA"},
            {"Date" : "jan-29-2019", "Id" : "#188", "Amount" : "250 Rs", "Shopping" : "Online", "Order_City" : "Hyderbad", "Order_State" : "TELANGANA"},
            {"Date" : "jan-25-2019", "Id" : "#176", "Amount" : "200 Rs", "Shopping" : "Online", "Order_City" : "Hyderbad", "Order_State" : "TELANGANA"},
            {"Date" : "jan-28-2019", "Id" : "#201", "Amount" : "250 Rs", "Shopping" : "Online", "Order_City" : "Hyderbad", "Order_State" : "TELANGANA"}
        ]

        self.qvw1 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(widgetResizable=True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.qvw1)

        self.online_order_hbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.qvw1)
        self.online_label = QtGui.QPushButton("Online Order")
        self.refreshlabel = QtGui.QPushButton("Refresh")
        self.refreshlabel.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-color: #FF8C00; color: white;outline : None;}")
        self.refreshlabel.clicked.connect(self.refresh_orders)
        self.online_label.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-color: #FF8C00; color: white;outline : None;}")
        self.online_order_hbox.addWidget(self.online_label,QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.online_order_hbox.addWidget(self.refreshlabel,QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        self.qvw1.setFixedWidth(550)

        self.refresh_orders()
    def refresh_orders(self):
        for i in self.Online_order_dict:

            w = InfoWidget(i)
            w.clicked.connect(self.on_info_clicked)
            self.online_order_hbox.addWidget(w)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)

    #self.Online_order_dict = self.result_data[1]
    # for j in self.Online_order_dict:
    #     l=j['created'].split("T")
    #     self.online = {"Date": str(l[0]),"Id" : "#"+str(j['pk']),"Total Amount":str(j['totalAmount']),"Order City":j['billingCity'],"Order State":j['billingState']}
    #     onlineList.append(self.online)
    # 
    # for index, i in enumerate(onlineList):
    #     w = InfoWidget1(index, i)
    #     w.clicked.connect(partial(self.on_info_clicked,"online"))
    #     self.online_order_hbox.addWidget(w)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_info_clicked(self):
        w = self.sender()
        print(w.info)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    settingobj= Orders()
    settingobj.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution in this case is to remove the InfoWidget before adding the new ones, for this we can obtain them through `findChildren()` method:

```
def refresh_orders(self):
    for w in self.online_order_hbox.parentWidget().findChildren(InfoWidget):
        w.deleteLater()
    for i in self.Online_order_dict:
        w = InfoWidget(i)
        w.clicked.connect(self.on_info_clicked)
        self.online_order_hbox.addWidget(w)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
```

Comment: @navyasri ask your question, nothing you lose with trying.

Comment: actually i want to call this function in each 10 seconds so i put this function in thread class but it is showing the error gui not safe like that i can;t understand why i am not able to call this class

Comment: @navyasri Why do you want to do it in a thread ?, the GUI can not be modified from another thread, what you should do is send the data through a signal to the GUI thread, and in the GUI thread you call the refresh_orders method

Comment: @navyasri If my answer helps you do not forget to mark my answer as correct

Comment: sir  i don't want to click another button to see my fresh orders that why i want to put that function in thread but that is not working so i choose this way

Comment: @navyasri What I point out is that you do not fill in the GUI from another thread, that is, you have your request to your API in the new thread but send the data to the main thread through signals.

Comment: @navyasri if you provide a [mcve] I could give you an example of code

Comment: @navyasri Why do you do that ?, I have not indicated that in my solution, and your error is obvious: the lists do not have that method

Comment: @navyasri no, that part is irrelevant, I delete the InfoWidget, I do not analyze Online_order_dict if you realize so you do not need to do that, I recommend you first analyze my answer before trying to modify it. My answer depends on [mcve], so I can not help you at all if you have a code that does not look like the MCVE, I'm just going to waste my time trying to guess what you're doing.

Comment: @navyasri with the code that you show in the comments you only have to modify `for i in self.Online_order_dict:` to `for index, i in enumerate(onlineList): w = InfoWidget1(index, i) ....`